# Word in vb: range.converttotable separator

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I am using the following namespace: `Microsoft.Office.Interop`

`oDocs` is my used Word-Instance

`intColumns` is the amount of columns (converting from datatable)

`intRows` is the amount of rows in the DataTable (+1 for colName)

```
    Dim rng As Word.Range
    rng = oDocs.Application.Selection.Range
    rng.Text = strTable
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table = rng.ConvertToTable(NumRows:=intRows + 1,  _
           NumColumns:=intColumns, Separator:=Word.WdSeparatorType.wdSeparatorColon)
```

This code is working quite good for most cases, but not for all.
The Problem: The separator does not seem to be unused in the Values. So sometimes the Table is not created correctly.

I know you can select an individual separator when using the converttotable method in Word itself. How can i do that programmatically instead of being forced to use one of the five Enums?

**Edit**

Got it Working! 
Cindy Meister brought me to the right path;

`Dim WordTable As Word.Table = rng.ConvertToTable(NumRows:=intRows + 1, NumColumns:=intColumns, Separator:="$")` 
"Spearator:= " suggests you do put en enum, you can also simply put a String with the .length of 1 into there. I used `'$'` because its probably not used in the DataTable Values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm, yes, this is not straightforward, but recording a macro reveals the secret...

When you set a custom separator using "Other" this sets the Word Application's `DefaultTableSeparator`. And there is an Enum for that:

```
Dim wdApp as Word.Application = oDocs.Application
Dim rng As Word.Range = wdApp.Selection.Range
wdApp.DefaultTableSeparator = "|"
rng.Text = strTable
Dim WordTable As Word.Table = rng.ConvertToTable(NumRows:=intRows + 1,  _
       NumColumns:=intColumns, _
       Separator:=Word.WdTableFieldSeparator.wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator)
```